# How to install an bower package under meteor?

Tags: meteor, bower, meteor-blaze, semantic-ui

I am trying to install this https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar package. I installed with `npm install -g bower` this browser package manager from my project folder. Then I installed this calendar package with `bower install --save semantic-ui-calendar` from my project folder.

After starting my app I get this error messages:

> While processing files with less (for target web.browser):
>
> bower_components/semantic-ui-calendar/src/definitions/modules/calendar.less:18:
>   Unknown import: ../../theme.config
>
> bower_components/semantic-ui-calendar/src/theme.less:3:8: variable
>   @themesFolder is undefined

Where should I include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/semantic-ui-calendar/dist/calendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/semantic-ui-calendar/dist/calendar.min.css" />
```

and

```
@import 'definitions/modules/calendar';
```

and

```
  lessOptions: {
    paths: [
      'bower_components/semantic-ui-calendar/src',
      ...
    ]
  }
```

from the installation guide? Will this calendar package work with meteor 1.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bower packages is deprecated. Since Meteor allowed use of npm packages directly, your desired bower package should have an npm equivalent, and can therefore be installed with npm install...

There was a package https://atmospherejs.com/mquandalle/bower which did allow bower modules to be installed, but you should probably avoid doing that too.